# Looping issue with Excel Forms

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a type mismatch error when running the following code on an Excel form with a check box. Not sure why as this code works for my other user forms just fine without this error. Also noticed others in the office can run this without the type mismatch error.

Code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
End Sub  

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Dim c As Control

    For Each c In Me.Controls '<----Error line
        If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If c Then
                Select Case c.Name    
                Case "CheckBox1"
                   'Code    
                Case Else
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    Hide
End Sub
```

I've attempted to use `For each c in Forms(UserForm1).controls` but it doesn't recognize the fact that the box is checked and runs the loop without running the code for the check box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Here are my current references

[image: References]

Comment: Instead of us assuming things from the start, what does `Me` refer to? Are you in the the code module of a userform?

Comment: A few points: this code doesn't compile. Where is `c` declared? It's always a good idea to enforce variable declaration using `Option Explicit` in *all* code/class/form modules.

Comment: Yes this is in the code module of the userform. Sorry forgot a few lines of code. Added them. Including `dim c as Control`

Comment: Your code is working fine for me as posted.  Regarding the apparent skip of `if c Then`, just making sure intended purpose is to check the VALUE of c, because c's default return value for that checkbox appears to be True/False for checked unchecked so if the box is unchecked it will fail this step.  What References do you have selected?

Comment: Try moving that "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library" to be right after "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library".

Comment: @GSerg thanks that did it!

Comment: @gserg can you explain _why_ that's important?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I'm not sure actually. Since it worked, there must be a type named `Control` in the ADO, DAO, or Outlook libraries that gets picked due to the reference order. But I cannot see such type in any of these libraries, and I cannot reproduce the issue when I reference the same libraries in the OP's original order.